# How to prove that $\text{cov}(y_i,\hat{y_i}) = \sigma^2 h_{ii}$

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

In one part of our notes (and some books), the following expression is used :

> For the generalized linear model  $y=X\beta + \epsilon$, it is :
>   $$\text{cov}(y_i,\hat{y_i})=\sigma^2h_{ii}$$

**Question :** How does one proceed with proving that formally ?

Comment: Could you define $\hat y_i, \sigma^2,h_{ii}$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom $\hat{y_i}$ is the estimator of $y_i$ of the expected value of the linear model, $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the model of the independent value $y_i$ and $h_{ii}$ the diagonal elements of the hat matrix $\mathbf{H}$.

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266026/what-is-operatornamecov-widehaty-y?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $y-E(y)=\epsilon$ and $\hat y = Hy$, so $\hat y - E(\hat y)=Hy - E(Hy)=H(y-E(y))=H\epsilon$. Then
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(y,\hat y) = E\left[(y-E(y))(\hat y - E(\hat y))^T\right]
=E(\epsilon\epsilon^TH)=\sigma^2H
$$
The $i,i$ diagonal element of the LHS is $\operatorname{Cov}(y_i, \hat y_i)$, while the $i,i$ diagonal element of the RHS is $\sigma^2 h_{i,i}$.

Comment: Nicely elaborated. I also proved that $$\text{Var}(\hat{y}_i) = \text{Var}\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n}h_{ij}y_j \right) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} h_{ij}^2 \text{Var}(y_j) = \sigma^2h_{ii}$$ but why would it be $\text{Var}(\hat{y_i}) = \text{cov}(y_i,\hat{y_i})$ ?

Comment: @Rebellos The statement  $\operatorname{cov}(y_i, \hat y_i)=\operatorname{cov}(\hat y_i, \hat y_i)$ is the same as the statement $\operatorname{cov}(y_i-\hat y_i, \hat y_i)=0$,  i.e., the $i$th residual is uncorrelated with the $i$th fitted value.